# Can't install modules in a sub site --- Seeing Ajax error

Tags: ajax

### Background

I have a Drupal 7.38 **folder subsite** (i.e `yoursitesname.com/test`). The site was installed with softaculous, and has only few core modules enabled. When I come to install the last version of [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), or alternatively, [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references), I get this error:

[image]

You can see from the first screen that the error tells me to continue to the "errors page" and this is what I see when I continue

[image]

### Already tried and didn't help

Some of the solutions were found in Google search:

- Flushed all caches.
- Installing from a downloaded file, instead of a link in Drupal.org.
- giving 755 permissions to all the homefolder files (including .HTaccess and all files in sites/default folder).
- Changing PHP version for main folder (i.e `yoursitesname.com`) from PHP 5.3.29 to PHP 5.5.26

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site was installed via Softaculous platform (Cpanel software). The original isntallation included some non-core modules and I removed all of them to the situation I had only core-modules... Yet, for some unkown reason, it prevented me from installing modules by the aforementioned error. But now... After I deleted the Softaculous install and installed Drupal 7.38 in the traditional "manual" way, the sub-site worked fine... It might be a bug in the current release of Softaculous, that prevents installation of modules in sub-sites.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of items to check:

- Clear all caches (it doesn't hurt, and occasionally helps solving various issues): if you get a WSOD while doing so, it indicates memory shortage.
- Try running `update.php` (by typing an URL like `http://www.yourdomain.com/update.php`): if you get a Fatal error like "Allow memory size of ... bytes exhausted", it indicates memory shortage.
- Verify if it is a memory shortage issue by increasing the memory a bit to check if there is any difference.

  Assuming this is NOT a multi site, consider editing your `/sites/default/settings.php`, and change the line to set the memory limit. If it is a multi site, then edit the `settings.php` file related to the site where you are experiencing the problem.

  That line in settings.php should look similar to this:

  `ini_set('memory_limit', '100M');`

  The '100M' in it might be some other number. Whatever the number is, try to increase it with like 50%, or maybe even double it to see what happens after you do so (of course do not forget to save the file after increasing that number).

  If needed, refer to https://www.drupal.org/node/207036 for more details, eg if such 'ini_set' is not yet included in your `settings.php` file. As mentioned in that link: "*Locate the PHP settings section and add that line at the end of that section*".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! some details: 
 
It's not a subsite... there is no error or problem while clearing caches. How do you run update.php?, I can't find such a syntax --- ini_set('memory_limit', '100M'); --- in settings.php ... Not in the subsite and not in the original site's settings.php ...

Comment: Expanded my answer a bit to address your prior comment ... curious to hear if that will help ...

Comment: Ran PHP in both sites (original and folder subsite), there where no problems... I also expanded the subsite' settings.php in the only section that contain the word "memory" (please see image in the bottom of my question). The error still appears...

Comment: Updated the question with more data.

Comment: Hm, that's different from memory problems then ... Seems like you need to find the module that causes that error, disable/uninstall that module, and then enable that module again. Doiing so you will trigger the logic in the .install file again, which might (re-) create the "undefined" index ... please keep me updated when you have more news on that